# Is it possible to reuse a string in java?

Tags: java, string, udp, client-server, reusability

I am trying to write a program, where I use UDP client/server to vote. The client inputs their candidate of choice, it is sent to the server, the server records the vote for a candidate and does this for 25 valid votes.

Entering the first vote works, However, my problem comes when entering the rest of votes, because I am using the same string in the while loop to compare the client vote to one of the strings in the array. 
(not sure if I'm explaining this clearly)

```
class UDPVoteServer {

public static final String[] candidates = new String[] {
    "Peter Singh",
    "Ricardo Allen",
    "Winston Alibocas",
    "Linda Jenkins", 
    "Marlene Williams"
};// 5 candidates to choose from

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9816);
    System.out.println("UDP Server Started\n");
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    int maxVotes = 0; int hacked = 0;
while(true){

        int success = 0;  int invalid  = 0; int numVotes = 0;
        String canVote= "";

        int[] record = new int [5]; // records votes for each of the 5 candidates
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) record[i] = 0;

        while (maxVotes < 25){

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

            String clientIP = receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress();

            System.out.println("Received vote from client IP "+clientIP );

            /*block a hacker IP from trying to vote*/
            String blockedIP = "109.211.55.44";


            if (clientIP.equals(blockedIP)){
                System.out.println("\nRestricted IP contact made");
                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();

                int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                String error = "Your machine has been debarred from voting!";

                sendData = error.getBytes();

                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                serverSocket.send(sendPacket);

                 hacked++;
                 break; //exit loop if a blocked ip tries to access server

          }

        String VoterPick = new String(receivePacket.getData());//from client
        canVote = VoterPick.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "); //removes extra white spaces
        System.out.println(canVote);

        InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
        int port = receivePacket.getPort();
        String result= "";

            for(String pick : candidates) {

                for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

                if(canVote.equalsIgnoreCase(pick)){ //checks to see if voter spelt candidate name correctly after removing unnecessary white space
                    //Calculate voting here   

                    record[i] = numVotes + 1; //adds a vote to the respective candidate


                     result = "Vote Successful";
                    success++;
                maxVotes++; //increment only if the vote was successful; therefore loop stops when there are 25 valid votes entered
                    sendData = result.getBytes();
                    break;  
                }

                //if spelt wrong record it as an invalid vote
                else { 
                     result = "Invalid Candidate";
                    invalid++;
                    sendData = result.getBytes();
                    break;  
                }
                }
            }

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);

            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);

            //maxVotes++;
            //canVote = ""; //this does not seem to work

        }
        System.out.println("Hacker tried to access server " +hacked+ " times.");
        System.out.println("Successful votes: " +success);
        System.out.println("Invalid Votes: " +invalid +"\n");
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                System.out.println(candidates[i] + " " + record[i]);
        }
     }
  }

}
```

I am trying to clear the information stored in the string canVote, so the new candidateVote can be stored in the string canVote, but it does not seem to work, and therefore i keep getting invalid candidate printed on client even when it had been entered correctly.

Is it possible to reuse the string canVote or is there another way to store the information?

Appreciate any help given.

Comment: numVotes is never assigned any value besides 0.  Not sure I see the point of the record array either since every element ends up the same.

Comment: the record array is to record the number of votes each candidate receives in order to output a winner. However that is unfinished code, i was trying to fix my String problem before making the program more complex and harder to debug.

Comment: I understand it's unfinished but that's left me confused.  Why would each candidate need 5 vote tallies?  What is meant by 25 valid votes?  25 voters? My current guess is that you don't need a static canVote to clear it and reuse it.  Help me understand the purpose behind the code and I'll be able to help.  Maybe add some comments to the code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist the `canVote` variable between function calls you can make it `static`, however you should be wary that it is not going to be thread-safe without additional logic.

```
// static class variable
private static String canVote = "";

// reference in your method as...
MyClass.canVote = "something";
```

There are also other persistent datastore options like a database, memcached, etc but you would again need to consider how thread-safe your code is.

Comment: This is the right answer (upvoted)... Changed my comment. Misread the question. Carry on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this:

```
        for(String pick : candidates) {

            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

                 if(canVote.equalsIgnoreCase(pick)){ //checks to see if voter spelt candidate name correctly after removing unnecessary white space
```

Does what you think it does.

That will loop 25 times when there are 5 candidates sure enough but for each candidate (named `pick`) it checkes the same `canVote` 5 times recording the same result in a different element of the `record` array.

You may be better off without the `i` loop and just incrementing `i` within the candidate loop.  You'll need an outer loop that continues until 25 valid votes have been cast.  Likely a `while` loop.